# Generate random numbers between -1 and 1 in java

Tags: java, random

This is what I am going to do. I want to generate random numbers between -1 and 1. Then I add that generated number to a specific number. I want to continue this until that total value reaches another specific value.

```
int distance = 5;
int min = -1;
int max = 1;
int randomValue;


   while(distance <= 10){
       randomValue = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
       distance = randomValue + distance;
       Log.d("Output", "value is"+distance);
   }
```

This returns values up to 11.  how can I resolve this

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java

Comment: what is your max expected value? 10 or 11?

Comment: max expected value is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
while(distance != 10) {
    // ...
}
```

With your current condition, you run the risk of adding one even when `distance` is already at 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
public int getRandomNumberUsingInts(int min, int max) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.ints(min, max)
      .findFirst()
      .getAsInt();
}
```

If you put max 2 and min -1, the randomly generated number will have 3 possibilities, They are: -1, 0, 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-1,2);` for your requirement. This will generate random numbers between -1 and +1. So the loop reads as,

```
    while(distance <= 10){
       randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min,max+1);
       distance = randomValue + distance;
       Log.d("Output", "value is"+distance);
   }
```

Only catch is that you'll need to increment max by 1 since the upper bound is exclusive.

Comment: tried this and gives 12 also as a value